# MyMonero wallet recovery with phrase

Tags: wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed, monero

I'm sorry to both you with this.

Mymonero.com has been down for several days and I'd like to remove the monero from my wallet on that website.

All I have is the original phrase I set it up with years ago though.

I downloaded the monero wallet from getmonero.com but it requires a 25 word phrase, I think mine is 13 words.

So I'm confused. Did mymonero.com use its own phrase to wallet system?

Most importantly:

**Is there anyway for me to recover the wallet without using MyMonero.com?**

Thank you very much for your help!